# Postgres. How to get all the parents that meet the childs criteria?

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursion

I'm a bit crazy looking for a solution for this problem:

I got something like this table:

Table Data

[image]

And I want a query to obtain all the elements that pass the condition and all the parents, I mean, this result:

Query Result

[image]

I've been thinking on the query:

```
SELECT a.* FROM table a 
    JOIN table b ON b.id = a.id
    WHERE a.id IN (SELECT DISTINCT c.parent_id FROM table c WHERE c.condition = TRUE)
    OR b.id IN (SELECT DISTINCT c.id FROM table c WHERE c.condition = TRUE);
```

But I can only get one level of difference with this method, I mean, I can't get more than 1 parent without the condition.
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a [recursive CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html) for this:

```
WITH RECURSIVE recCTE AS
(
    /*Get all the true children to seed the recursive query*/
    SELECT
        id,
        parent_id,
        condition as initial_condition,
        1 as depth,
        CAST(id as varchar(50)) as path
    FROM
        table a
    WHERE
        a.id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT parent_id from table)
        and a.condition = 'true'

    UNION ALL

    /*Recursive bit that refers back to itself. Find the parents*/
    SELECT
        b.id,
        b.parent_id,
        a.initial_condition,
        depth + 1 as depth,
        cast(path || '>' || b.id as varchar(50)) as path        

    FROM
        recCTE a
        INNER JOIN table b ON
            a.parent_id = b.id
    WHERE
        /*avoid going too deep in case of cycling*/
        depth <= 20
)
SELECT * FROM recCTE
```

The recursive CTE uses two parts:

1. The Recursive Seed: This is the first half of the UNION query. In this we identify all of the children (ID's that aren't also Parent_IDs) that are "True"
2. The Recursive Term: This is the second half of the UNION query. It refers back to itself (recCTE) in the FROM clause and joins `table` in again; linking the recCTE.parent_id (previous iterations parent_id) to the table's `id`. Then pulls all the information needed for that iteration.

I almost always track the recursive depth (how many recursions did it take to get to this record), and the path (Starting from the bottom most child which other nodes of this hierarchy did we hit to get to this record).

I use the depth to insure that we don't go too far down the rabbit hole. In the event that you have records like:

```
+----+-----------+
| id | parent_id |
+----+-----------+
|  1 |         5 |
|  5 |         7 |
|  7 |         1 |
+----+-----------+
```

Which would cause an infinite loop (cycling) the worst case scenario is it will stop after it goes 20 cycles deep (1>5>7>1>5>7>1>5>7>1>5>7>1>5>7>1>5>7>1>5). There are other ways to stop cycling, like using the path field:  `WHERE a.path NOT LIKE '%' || a.parent_id || '%'` for example.

You can get a bit fancier with that final select if you need to, but this will get you 95% of the way there.

Comment: Wow man, really nice explanation, I became crazy with this, I read a little bit about recursive CTE and are amazings!
Completely saved the day thanks to you. I adapted the query to my table and was fine :D

Comment: Great! I'm glad it worked for you out of the box. There's definitely a learning curve to Recursive CTE's but once you get your head around them they make perfect sense and a great tool for the toolbox.